# How to drop columns with missing data only towards the end in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which contains a variable number of columns (The no of columns in each row is determined by a particular value in the row).

Here is the current method I am using:-

```
pd.read_csv(file_path, names=list(range(100)).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

This drops all columns which are completely empty.

The only problem is there can be columns in the middle which consist of empty values. Eg:-

```
abc |    | def | 20  | 1 | 2 | ..... | x |  |  |
def |    | ghi | 10  | 1 | 2 | ..... |   |  |  |
ghi |    | jkl | 20  | 1 | 2 | ..... | y |  |  |
```

Here, I want to keep the 2nd column, even if its completely empty, but remove the columns at the end which are completely empty. Basically, this should be converted to:-

```
abc |    | def | 20  | 1 | 2 | ..... | x
def |    | ghi | 10  | 1 | 2 | ..... |  
ghi |    | jkl | 30  | 1 | 2 | ..... | y
```

As the dataframe has thousands of rows, looping over would be too slow. Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this example input as `df`:

```
   0   1    2  3   4   5
0  1 NaN  3.0  4 NaN NaN
1  1 NaN  3.0  4 NaN NaN
2  1 NaN  NaN  4 NaN NaN
3  1 NaN  3.0  4 NaN NaN
```

you can compute if the column is empty using `df.notna().any(0)` (or any other method if you prefer to have a threshold of a different condition), which gives (as array): `[ True, False, False,  True, False, False]`.

Then the trick is to use `cumsum` on the reverse array to keep the False values at the end, but to fill the previous ones:

```
mask = df.notna().any(0)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].astype(bool)
# [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False]
```

which you can use to slice the columns:

```
>>> df.loc[:,mask]  # or df.loc(1)[mask]
   0   1    2  3
0  1 NaN  3.0  4
1  1 NaN  3.0  4
2  1 NaN  NaN  4
3  1 NaN  3.0  4
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems good; Just a small correction - I believe it should be `any()` instead of `all()` as `all` will require all values in the column to be true but we want to keep the column even if 1 value is true

Comment: @Yashovardhan99 of course you're right, I initially used `isna` and I forgot to swap the `all` to `any` ;)